# Using await in Vue interceptor

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, interceptor

How do I use await inside of an interceptor? I have tried the below code but it does not print the value.

```
http.interceptors.push(async (req, next) => {
    final value = await someAsyncFunction();
    console.log(value);
})
```

I also tried this code, which works but I want to use await since I need to execute some code after it synchronously.

```
http.interceptors.push(async (req, next) => {
    someAsyncFunction().then(value => console.log(value));
    executeSomethingElse();
})
```

Comment: It's not "vue" interceptor, it's Axios. `final value =` - this syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use the anonymous function on the interceptor, so you should write it like these

```
http.interceptors.push(async function (req, next) {
    await someAsyncFunction()
})
```

This is because Vue cannot access the `this` property on the background.

Comment: `this` isn't used in the OP. It's unknown what is the scope for this code and whether the use of `this` is acceptable, so it's not evident that an arrow is a problem